# Altering a laravel pagination object

Tags: php, laravel

I set up server side pagination for some of my views.
Given this code in the blade template:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  {{ $sale_history->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-5') }}
</div>
```

I'm curious why this controller works

```
class SaleController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $sale_history = Sale::orderByDesc('date')->paginate(15);

        $sale_history->each(function(&$sale) {
            
            $sale->customer_name = User::find($sale->customer_id)->displayname ?? "";
            $sale->product_name = $sale->product()->pluck('title')->first();
            $sale->product_expiry = $sale->subscription()->pluck('expiry_date')->first() ?? '';
            $sale->payment_amount = Money::EUR($sale->payment_gross()); //
            $sale->sale_points = $sale->points() ?? 0;
            $sale->sale_status = Str::ucfirst($sale->status);
        });

        return view('layouts.sales.index')->with(compact('sale_history'));
    }
}
```

But this doesn't

```
class SaleController extends Controller
{

    private function prepare_data($list){

        return $list->each(function(&$sale) {
            
            $sale->customer_name = User::find($sale->customer_id)->displayname ?? "";
            $sale->product_name = $sale->product()->pluck('title')->first();
            $sale->product_expiry = $sale->subscription()->pluck('expiry_date')->first() ?? '';
            $sale->payment_amount = Money::EUR($sale->payment_gross());
            $sale->sale_points = $sale->points() ?? 0;
            $sale->sale_status = Str::ucfirst($sale->status);
        });
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $sale_history = Sale::orderByDesc('date')->paginate(15);
        $sale_history = $this->prepare_data($sale_history);

        return view('layouts.sales.index')->with(compact('sale_history'));
    }
}
```

and produces this error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.

So.. why does passing my data to a function as an argument causes it to lose its pagination references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning the value of `$sale_history` in the second example but not the first example. The value returned from `each` in your examples is the Collection contained within the Paginator instance; there is no `each` method for a Paginator, it forwards the call to the Collection it contains. The `each` method of Collections returns itself. So the return value from `each` is not the Paginator but a Collection so you should not be assigning that value to `$sale_history` as you now don't have a reference to the Paginator.

Also you don't need to reference the value being passed into the closure you are using, it is an object so it is already going to alter the object, not a copy of it.

TLDR: You are assigning the return value of `each`, which returns a Collection, to your variable. You don't need to reassign the variable as you want `$sale_history` to remain as the Paginator object.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. So, how do I alter my pagination object while keeping it a pagination object? I would like to have that in a separate function because I'll be applying the same alterations in different controller functions serving the same view. 
TBH I don't understand what this means and how to translate it into code "you don't need to reference the value being passed into the closure you are using".

Comment: don't reassign the value ... just run `each` without assigning the value to anything ... `$sale_history` is already your pagination object you don't need to reassign that .... and the closure `$list->each(function(&$sale)`, you don't need the `&`, reference, as its an object being passed in